# Does git no longer support automatic rebasing?

Tags: git

Very recently `git` has started merging even though I have set it to always rebase:

```
$ git config --list | grep -F branch.autosetup
branch.autosetuprebase=always
$ git pull
[Removed everything in the commit message]
error: Empty commit message.
Not committing merge; use 'git commit' to complete the merge.
$ git merge --abort
```

It was definitely a trivial merge, because:

```
$ git pull --rebase
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: [...]
$ echo $?
0
```

Is this a known issue?

```
$ git --version
git version 2.3.1
```

Answer (score 3):

Turns out `branch.autosetup` only takes effect on *new* branches, creating a repository-local `branch.[branch].rebase=true` setting. To set this retroactively for the `master` branch:

```
$ git config branch.master.rebase true
```

My bad.